# Failed to upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, laptop, vaio

This error prevents the system from upgrading to a newer version of Ubuntu, what is causing it?

```
 W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources      404  Not Found

 W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Since I got the warning message that this release is not supported anymore, should I download and install Ubuntu 12.10 directly from Ubuntu's site instead?

Comment: The actual error is missing. Please run the following command in a terminal and provide the full output it produces: `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker: Done. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately it's only the extras repo that's not working. You can disable that in the software sources application or by editing the relevant file in `/etc/apt`. After that, the upgrade to 11.10 should work. It's also advisable to upgrade to 12.04 LTS after upgrading to 11.10 as 11.10 is only supported for a few more months and 12.04 LTS for at least <strike>2</strike> 4 (see below) more years (and a few months).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you elaborate on how to disable it?

Comment: 12.04 LTS will be supported until April 2017. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: Each repository is listed in either /etc/apt/sources.list or in a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d - to disable the usage of a repository, open the file in a text editor as root (`gksudo gedit filename_goes_here`) and place a `#` in front of the line you want to disable. Any line that mentions extras.ubuntu.com should be disabled.

Comment: @fabricator4 - ah, must have missed that change in release policy, thanks for the addition.